# Why are times being interpreted differently in different time zones?

Tags: ios, swift, date, time, dateformatter

```
import UIKit
import Foundation

let dateString = "2017-08-13T05:10:00Z"
let dateFormatter = ISO8601DateFormatter()

if var date = dateFormatter.date(from: dateString) {
    if let newYorkTimeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "EDT") {
        date.addTimeInterval(TimeInterval(newYorkTimeZone.secondsFromGMT(for: date)))
        print("NY time:", date, date.hour())
    }
}

if var date = dateFormatter.date(from: dateString) {
    if let chiTimeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "CDT") {
        date.addTimeInterval(TimeInterval(chiTimeZone.secondsFromGMT(for: date)))
        print("CHI time:", date, date.hour())
    }
}

if let gmt = TimeZone(abbreviation: "GMT") {
    if var date = dateFormatter.date(from: dateString) {
        print("GMT time:", date, date.hour())
    }
}

extension Date {
    func hour() -> String {
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "h:mm a"

        return dateFormatter.string(from: self)
    }
}
```

---

**output while my system is set to EDT:**

NY time: 2017-08-13 01:10:00 +0000 9:10 PM

CHI time: 2017-08-13 00:10:00 +0000 8:10 PM

GMT time: 2017-08-13 05:10:00 +0000 1:10 AM

---

**output while my system is set to CDT:**

NY time: 2017-08-13 01:10:00 +0000 8:10 PM

CHI time: 2017-08-13 00:10:00 +0000 7:10 PM

GMT time: 2017-08-13 05:10:00 +0000 12:10 AM

---

Shouldn't these times stay the same no matter what time zone I am in? I am not using anything related to `TimeZone.current`.

Note: I know that it is better practice to use `TimeZone.secondsFromGMT:`, but using the abbreviation parameter makes it easier to read what's happening in this question.

Comment: Your code makes no sense. A Cocoa date object is an instant in time all across the planet. As I write this, it's about 1:00PM EDT, and about 12:00 PM central time. Why would the same `Date` object show as the same time in different time zones?

Comment: You should use a date formatter set to your desired time zone to express that date in local time.

Comment: The only thing different between your two sets of output are the results of the call to `hour` and your `hour` function is based on your current locale and current timezone. So of course those values change when you change your system's timezone.

Comment: Don't use time zone abbreviations.  They can be ambiguous.  Always used the long form [tzdb identifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones), such as `America/New_York`, `America/Chicago`, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my version of your code from a playground.

```
import UIKit

let dateString = "2017-08-13T05:10:00Z"
let isoDateFormatter = ISO8601DateFormatter()
guard let date = isoDateFormatter.date(from: dateString) else { assert(false) }

let gmtDateFormatter = DateFormatter()
gmtDateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(secondsFromGMT: 0)!
gmtDateFormatter.dateStyle = .medium
gmtDateFormatter.timeStyle = .medium

let nyDateFormatter = DateFormatter()
nyDateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "EDT")!
nyDateFormatter.dateStyle = .medium
nyDateFormatter.timeStyle = .medium

let chiDateFormatter = DateFormatter()
chiDateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "CDT")!
chiDateFormatter.dateStyle = .medium
chiDateFormatter.timeStyle = .medium

let gmtDate = gmtDateFormatter.string(from: date) // -> Aug 13, 2017, 5:10:00 AM
let nyDate = nyDateFormatter.string(from: date) // -> Aug 13, 2017, 1:10:00 AM
let chiDate = chiDateFormatter.string(from: date) // -> Aug 13, 2017, 12:10:00 AM
```

A date is a fixed point in time, it has no timezone, or daylight savings. To get a *string representation* of a time, use a `DateFormatter` with the applied timezone. My playground is set to the default US locale, but I can change any of the date formatters' locales to show the date and time differently.

You don't need to add intervals to the date you have, you just need to format it's output and that is what a DateFormatter is for.

Comment: Ok I understand now. I should be altering the way the date presents w/ `DateFormatter`, not trying to alter the `Date` itself.

Answer (score 0):

Consider this code:

```
let now = Date()

let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.dateStyle = .medium
formatter.timeStyle = .medium

func printDate(_ aDate: Date, inTimeZone timeZoneString: String? = nil) {
  let timeZone: TimeZone!
  if let timeZoneString = timeZoneString {
    timeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: timeZoneString)
    guard timeZone != nil else {
      print("invalid time zone string \(timeZoneString)")
      return
    }
  } else {
    timeZone = TimeZone.current
  }
  formatter.timeZone = timeZone
  print("Date = \(formatter.string(from: now)) in time zone \(timeZone.abbreviation()!)")
}

printDate(now)
printDate(now, inTimeZone: "CDT")
printDate(now, inTimeZone: "GMT")
printDate(now, inTimeZone: "NZST")
```

Run in EDT: the output is:

```
Date = Aug 12, 2017, 1:17:13 PM in time zone EDT
Date = Aug 12, 2017, 12:17:13 PM in time zone CDT
Date = Aug 12, 2017, 5:17:13 PM in time zone GMT
Date = Aug 13, 2017, 5:17:13 AM in time zone GMT+12
```